# Python character counter to list

Tags: python, counter

I've got a list with characters

```
chars  =  ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n',
           'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '-']
```

Then a Counter object

```
from collections import Counter

s = 'testing'
counter = Counter(s)
print(counter)

 >>> Counter({'t': 2, 'e': 1, 's': 1, 'i': 1, 'n': 1, 'g': 1})
```

How do I get a list from this `Counter` object that would have the same order and length as the `chars` list? The output list would contain integers so if the string did not contain the character there would be a `0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following list comprehension:

```
>>> [counter.get(c, 0) for c in chars]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 5):

Could just do it *without* a Counter. At least for long strings, it's faster (don't remember for short strings):

```
[*map(s.count, chars)]
```

Comment: Nice one, although I'd prefer `list(map(...))` for readability.

Comment: I've been doing that so often, I don't even think about it anymore, it's just normal to me :-). Plus for small cases I think it's faster.